# How to call cloud function inside another cloud function and pass some input parameters or argument using python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have total 3 cloud functions, 1st cloud function which has some conditions, if condition is true then it should trigger 2nd and 3rd cloud function and also pass required arguments or parameters to 2nd and 3rd cloud function before it triggers them.
I have tried separate execution of all of three but I need help in performing above scenario.

Cloud function-1 code in python:

```
def main(request):
    dest_table_name = 'my_dest_table' 
    myquery = "select count(*) size from `myproject.mydataset.mytable`"
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job = client.query(myquery)
    result = job.result()
    for row in results:
        print("Total rows available: ",row.size)
    if row.size != 0:
        pass "dest_table_name" to 2nd cloud function and execute it.
        pass "dest_table_name" to 3rd cloud function and execute it.
    else:
        print("query result is empty")
```

Comment: Do you need parallel execution? What is the whole time of all your function (in sequential and in worse case)? Do you have to handle return status in the 1st function? Do you need to handle retries?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, execution of 2nd and 3rd cloud function will be parallel, No need to handle return status in 1st function and also there is no need of retries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options are:

- call the function via an HTTP trigger, e.g. with `requests.get(<your function URL>)` and pass parameters as URL parameters;
- create a PubSub topic and have your functions produce/consume PubSub messages; or:
- just factor all your shared functions into the same file and call it as a regular Python function.

The latter will have significantly less overhead, but may contribute to a longer overall function runtime.

Comment: are you asking me to do something like this : https://kite.com/python/examples/4636/requests-send-the-url-parameters-of-a-get-request-in-order

Answer (score 0):

With your details and requirements, I recommend you to use PubSub and to do this

- Create a PubSub topic
- Deploy the function #2 with a trigger on PubSub event on the previously created topic
- Deploy the function #3 with a trigger on PubSub event on the previously created topic
- Function #1 create a PubSub message with the right parameters and published it
- Function #2 and #3 are trigger in parallel with the message published in the PubSub. They extracts the parameters from it and do the process

By the way, you are not coupled, you are scalable, you are parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Cloud PubSub as the connection layer, but it is also possible to trigger a cloud function from another cloud function directly using the Cloud Function URL and Google-signed ID token (to authorize the request).

```
import json
import urllib

import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token

data = {"id": "", "client": "", "path": ""}

req = urllib.request.Request(FUNCTION_URL, data=json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8"))

auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, FUNCTION_URL)

req.add_header("Authorization", f"Bearer {id_token}")
req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
res = response.read()
```

More info can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#generating_tokens_programmatically